# Редирект кроме картинок

Tags: .htaccess, редирект

> Добрый день! Переносим сайт с одного домена на другой (точнее с поддомена, но не суть)... Но пути к иллюстрациям (jpg, png, gif и файлам pdf) оставляем, как в таком случае настроить редирект, чтобы все запросы кроме картинок перемащали на новый ресурс...
>   Делаем так, но иллюстрации при заданном абсолютном пути не подгружаются при данном редиректе...

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://new.com/$1 [L]

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, вроде работает! ;)

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} old.com
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|pdf)$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule (.*) https://new.com/$1 [L]
```